# Prettier configured with Eslint giving error in quotes even when `singleQuotes` set to true

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, eslint, prettier

This is my `.eslintrc.json` file for the react app.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": ["react-app", "prettier"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": [
            "warn",
            {
                "singleQuote": true,
                "trailingComma": "es5",
                "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
                "useTabs": true
            }
        ],
        "arrow-body-style": "off",
        "prefer-arrow-callback": "off",
        "quotes": ["error", "single"]
    }
}
```

These are my dependencies in `package.json` file (this is not full code of the file, only dependencies)

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.22.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "6.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "5.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.0.8",
        "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "3.9.0",
        "install-peerdeps": "^3.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "typescript": "^4.2.4"
    }
}
```

I am facing error that even though `singleQuote` of prettier is set to `true`. Even for eslint, I have set `quote` as `single`.

[image]

My VS code settings for prettier-

[image]

Comment: Your eslint and prettier might be competing in auto formatting your code. Also, check out [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier).

Comment: Yes I know about this package and we can use `eslint-config-prettier` command to check for any conflicting rules but the quotes in both prettier and eslint were set to 'single' so it definitely wasn't the issue. It's been resolved now, the answer below solved my problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the docs: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quotes

It specifically states "JSX quotes ignore this option – see jsx-single-quote."

Set `jsxSingleQuote` to `true`